# Linq update list whilst looping through list

Tags: linq

I have a list which is accessible as follows:

```
List<PingtreeNode> _pingtree;

IEnumerable<PingtreeNode> ActiveNodes
{
    get { return _pingtree.Where(x => x.Status == PingtreeNodeStatus.Ready);}
}
```

I also have a method, who's job it is to iterate over some of the ActiveNodes where a RuleClass exists. For each of these nodes, a validation method is called and if the node is found to be invalid, a new PingtreeNodeStatus is set.

```
    void ValidateBuyerRules()
    {
        var nodes = ActiveNodes.Where(x => x.RuleClass.IsNotNullOrEmpty());

        foreach (var n in nodes)
        {
            var isValid = NewRuleSet(n.RuleClass).Validate(_appForm);

            if (!isValid) n.Status = PingtreeNodeStatus.FailedCritera;
        }
    }
```

One of the properties of PingtreeNode is 'Product', and a product can exists several times within the list ActiveNodes.

What I want to do is this. If isValid is true for a product, I need to set all subsequent nodes containing the same Product to a PingtreeNodeStatus.FailedCriteria. In other words ignore them further down the nodes list and don't perform validation on them.

I know how to iterate through the loop and do this but am concerned about updating a list whilst already being inside the list. Is there a safe way of achieving this?

Comment: _"Is there a safe way of achieving this?"_ Do you get an exception?

Comment: I don't get an exception but that doesn't mean there isn't the possibility of one that I haven't considered due to my lack of experience.

Comment: If you don't get an exception your code is safe and this question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to update a list while iterating over it, however that's not what you're doing.
You're not modifying the list but properties of the items in the list, this is perfectly safe.